# Django Rest returning related items for each item

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I was trying to find answer in similiar questions, but none was meeting my expectations.

I have 2 models:

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    music_type = models.CharField(max_lenght=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Event(models.Model):
    event_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ...
    artists = models.ManyToManyField(Artist)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.event_name
```

I also have `serializers.py` file:

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = '__all__'


class ArtistSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    events = EventSerializer(source='event_set', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Artist
        fields ='__all__'
```

The `event` in `ArtistSerializer` allows me to return all events where artist takes part.
Now for each artist I would like to get list of all artists if they ever were taking part in the same event.

For example I have 5 Artists (A1...A5) and 3 Events (E1...E3)
In Event 1: [A1,A3]

In Event 2: [A3,A4,A5,A2]

In Event 3: [A2, A3]

```
So for A3 I would like to get list [A1,A4,A5,A2]
For A1: [A3]
For A2: [A3,A4,A5]
```

Unfortunately I have huge problem to create this query as SQL-query and ORM mechanism looks more complicated in this situation. Can somebody help me with this problem or give hints how to solve this?

If it's needed I'm gonna share more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the through model to get the artists related to an event. This is the intermediate model which django will have created to make that M2M relationship.

Where you have a `ManyToManyField` it has an attribute of `through` which is the M2M model.

So from your event model you could do something like `Event.artists.through.objects.all()` and you'd see all the instances in your M2M model.

So to find out the artists which are linked to a given event you could query that same table;

`Event.artists.through.objects.filter(event_id=1).select_related('artist')`

This would then return all the objects in the M2M which belong to Event 1. You could then get the artists from there, or just grab the artist IDs `Event.artists.through.objects.filter(event_id=1).values_list('artist_id, flat=True)`

Given the scenario in your comment...

If you have an artist, then you can run a query to get the events they've been in, and then run another query with those event ids. In that second query you are then looking to get the artist ids that aren't the current artist you're already looking at.

```py
# First get the events that the current artist has been in
event_ids = Event.artists.through.objects.filter(artist_id=1).values_list('event_id, flat=True)

# Then get the other artists who have been in the same events
other_artist_ids = Event.artists.through.objects.filter(event_id__in =event_ids).exclude(artist_id=1).values_list('artist_id, flat=True)

# or the full instances
other_artists = Event.artists.through.objects.filter(event_id__in =event_ids).exclude(artist_id=1).select_related('artist')
```

Comment: Well I have endpoint where I return event and all artist who belong to this event. Now for each artist I want to grab list of other artists if they have ever been in any event together. Tbh it's a little complicated for me. If I understand your answer well I have to iterate over every event, get all artists and find solution not to duplicate them if they are in other event?

Comment: I've tried to show an example of that scenario

Comment: Okey, so I was testing this and it works for hardcoded artist_id=1. I also had to set other_artist_ids query as 'set' to not returns duplicate. And I have another question - what is the best way to return this data as JSON? Get all event's id, iterate over and change artist_id and the execute second query? Or is it way better option to do this?

Comment: You should be able to override the queryset on your endpoints to take data from the request so that you can get this to work dynamically.

Comment: I think I still don't know django rest well to deal with this solution. Could you look at my project at github? https://github.com/f4lco0n/grywit_task - it's not updated with view with your queries above

Comment: It looks like you haven't got an endpoint setup yet, just some basic methods and some 2 points to create things. I think you need to build a bit more before you fit this query in.